Defining the area enclosed by a Jordan curve.
I specifically made an account just to ask this question and it is thus my first post. Please excuse any errors or faux-pas in posing this question.

Summary:
Let $\gamma$ be a Jordan curve (simple closed curve in $\mathbb{C}$) (specifically nowhere differentiable and non-rectifiable) and $I_\gamma$ its interior.
I can define the area of $I_\gamma$ as something like
$$
|I_\gamma| = \int_{I_\gamma} d\omega,
$$
where $\omega$ is a 1-form (is this correct?).
(Side question: Is it possible that defining the area like this leads to an issue for some specific type of curves like fractals? I'd guess that since we start with the Jordan curve, this shouldn't be an issue.)
Can I then use the Stokes' theorem to write
$$
\int_\gamma \omega = \int_{I_\gamma} d \omega \,?
$$
More specifically can I at least say that if $\gamma$ is a jordan curve and $\tilde{\gamma}$ some other curve such that $\int_{\gamma - \tilde{\gamma}} = \int_{0}$, I can do something like the following
$$
|I_\gamma|-|I_{\tilde{\gamma}}| = \int_{I_\gamma}d\omega - \int_{I_{\tilde{\gamma}}}d\omega = \int_\gamma\omega -\int_{\tilde{\gamma}}
\omega = 0\, ?$$

Some background
In the case of sufficiently smooth curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{C}$ there is this very nice result that the area $I_\gamma$ enclosed by this curve can be computed as
$$\label{test}
|I_\gamma| = \frac{1}{2i}\int_\gamma z^*dz\, .
$$
When playing around with a few curves and linear transformation (*) for these curves, I noticed that the area enclosed by these curves did not change after some of these transformations.
The way I computed these integrals was numerically, so I chose some grid $\sigma_k$ on $[0,1]$ and computed
$$
|I_\gamma| \approx |I_{\gamma,\textbf{num}}| = \frac{1}{2i}\sum_k \gamma^*(\sigma_k) (\gamma(\sigma_{k+1})-\gamma(\sigma_k))\, .
$$
Afterwards  I managed to show for that if $\tilde{\gamma}$ is the transformed curve, for all grids $\sigma_k$,
$$
|I_{\gamma,\textbf{num}}|-|I_{\tilde{\gamma},\textbf{num}}|=0 .
$$
Eventually this led me to formulate my conjecture in a more general setting, whenever
$$
\int_{\gamma - \tilde{\gamma}} = \int_{0}
$$
the areas enclosed by $\gamma$ and $\tilde{\gamma}$ are equal.
Since we are basically using Stokes theorem here, I did notice that the transformed curve $\tilde{\gamma}$ may not be a Jordan curve, meaning that I might have loops of "negative" area when the orientation of the curve is negative (imagine an 8-loop where one part has positive area and the other has "negative" area because we flipped the curves orientation).
As I tried to find the details of Stokes theorem the definition becomes very technical or requires a sufficiently smooth manifold $\omega$ ($I_\gamma$).
Since $\gamma$ may be nowhere differentiable, I think the assumption for stokes theorem does not apply anymore.
So my question is basically: Can I equate the area of two sets $I_\gamma$ and $I_{\tilde{\gamma}}$ if $\int_{\gamma - \tilde{\gamma}} = \int_{0}$? or at least if $|I_{\gamma,\textbf{num}}|-|I_{\tilde{\gamma},\textbf{num}}|=0$?
Thank you for your help!
(*) the type of transformation:
$$
\tilde{\gamma} = \sum_k c_k \gamma\circ T[t_k]
$$
where $T$ is a shift of the curve parameter i.e. $T[t_k]\gamma(t) = \gamma(t+t_k)$, and $c_k\in\mathbb{C}$ and $t_k\in[0,1]$ (assuming that $\gamma: [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$).
